# R studio cannot find existing library

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, gsl

It seems that R studio cannot find a library (DirichletMultinomial.so)

I installed this library through R in command line. I had problem installing it with Rstudio, because this package requires gsl, which I compiled on my own (don't have sudo priviledge). I added the path of gsl libs to my $PATH and R command line was able to use it to install the packages. But Rstudio somehow still reports "gsl-config: command not found". It seems that Rstudio ignore my set up of $PATH completely and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
> library(TFBSTools)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘TFBSTools’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '/bar/cfan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/DirichletMultinomial/libs/DirichletMultinomial.so':
libgsl.so.23: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

cfan@paleAle:~$ wc -l /bar/cfan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/DirichletMultinomial/libs/DirichletMultinomial.so
273 /bar/cfan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/DirichletMultinomial/libs/DirichletMultinomial.so
```

Comment: You have an old R version, [try updating it](https://cran.r-project.org/). Then (or alternatively) try a re-install. `remove.packages("TFBSTools")` then `install.packages("TFBSTools")`. Doesn't matter if the remove fails. Note the _error_  messages and report back.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment! However, I don't think the problem is with R version. My R command line is using the same version as R studio, but somehow it works very well while R studio gives the error. I'm trying to understand the discrepancy between command line and R studio

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry for removing the `rstudio` tag. Perhaps you may want to report your issue there: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues